# Overflow:scroll not working in google chrome

Tags: html, css, user-interface

This doesnt work in chrome.

```
.content {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Please suggest.
Thanks

Comment: Can you show this CSS in context? A jsfiddle example would be great.

Comment: you are trying to scroll without giving a `width` check the DEMO. http://jsbin.com/qiminina/1/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try by adding it to your code

```
{
width : 100px;
height :100px;
}
```

I feel it Works

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify a `width` on the div otherwise you won't be able to scroll.

Check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/qiminina/1/edit)**.

```
.content {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
  width:200px; /*Required*/
  height:200px; /*Required*/
}
```

Comment: strange my answer didn't work for you?

Comment: not working now chrome 60.